# DLast equivalent in .Net

Tags: .net, ms-access, vba

In Microsoft Access, there is this [DLast](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlast.php) function that returns the application key of the last value from a specified set of records. I wonder what is the equivalent of DLast in .Net that enables me to retrieve the primary key of my last insert?

I am using Access over OLEDBConnection

Answer (score 1):

How come you compare Access and .NET? If you want to express the same in SQL, for thos:

```
DLast("UnitPrice", "Order Details", "OrderID = 10248")
```

it will be something like

```
select top 1 UnitPrice 
    from OrderDetails 
    where OrderID = 10248 
    order by UnitPrice desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Which database are you using? Is it Access over an OLEDB connection? In that case you can run the DLast function in a query like this:

```
SELECT DLast("COLUMNNAME","TABLENAME","WHERE CLAUSE");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your Database system, not your development framework (.NET for example).

For SQL Server, take a look at the [@@Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx) system function.